# how to calculate $\int_{C}(2x^2+1)e^{x^2+y^2}dx+(2xy)e^{x^2+y^2}dy$ using Green theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

> Compute $\int_{C}(2x^2+1)e^{x^2+y^2}dx+(2xy)e^{x^2+y^2}dy$ where $C$ connects $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ by a straight line segment.

I tried to use green theorem since $Q_x = P_y$ so $\int \vec F_\dot{}\vec dr=0$

i need to close $C$ so i build a triangle with vertices 
$(0,0)$ , $(1,0)$ ,$(0,1)$ now i got a complicated integral in the line parametrization :

$y = 0 ~~~ dy=0$

$x = t ~~~ dx=dt$

$0\leq t \leq 1$

> $\int_0^1 (2t^2 + 1)e^{t^2}dt$  , since $dy=0$ only the left side stays

any hints how i can build an easy enclosier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e^{x^2+y^2}$ is a radial function, it is better to choose $D:(\cos t,\sin t), 0\le t\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and use the fact
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{C}(2x^2+1)e^{x^2+y^2}dx+(2xy)e^{x^2+y^2}dy&=&\int_{D}(2x^2+1)e^{x^2+y^2}dx+(2xy)e^{x^2+y^2}dy\\
&=&e\int_D (2x^2+1)dx + 2xydy\\
&=&e\left[\left(\frac{2}{3}x^3+x\right)\Big|^0_1+\frac{2}{3}\right]\\
&=&-e.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: yes i got it now alone thaaaaanks ! i am glad to notice that

Answer (score 1):

Seeing $x^2+y^2$ in the expression hints at circles and polar coordinates. I would suggest connecting the two given points with the quarter of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in the first quadrant. Then you can parametrize it as $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$, for $0\le t\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: thank you i noticed that right after asking the question !

Comment: i have question though can i use implicit function theorem ?

Comment: $ x^2 + y^2 = 1$ $2x + 2yy' = 0$ $dy = \frac{-x}{y} dx$

Comment: @Mather: Use it for what? Here you need to find both $dx$ and $dy$ with respect to $t$ from the chosen parametrization, not with respect to each other. For example, $x=\cos t$, so $dx=-\sin t\,dt$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\int x e^{x^2 + y^2} d(y^2) = x e^{x^2 + y^2} + C(x)$, we can see that $\phi(x, y) = x e^{x^2 + y^2}$ is a potential for $\mathbf F$. Then, by the gradient theorem,
$$I = \int_C (\nabla \phi) \cdot d\mathbf r = \phi(0, 1) - \phi(1, 0) = -e.$$